# Adding a custom field in Drupal Views Exposed filter using code

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I've a problem with Drupal  Views. My requirement is to add a custom select box in exposed filters.This select box contains some field names (the names of the fields in the views sort criteria), and when i select a value in this list, I must get the result in sorted order based on the selected value in the select box.
How can I do this?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to set the view style to **table**. Then for the table style options you can specify which columns (fields) can be used for sorting and you can define a default sorting field. As a bonus you can set AJAX to yes, so the sorting of the table doesn't trigger the page reload.